# How to prevent knitr from printing ## and matrix indices/row numbers?

Tags: r, pdf, printing, knitr, indices

Lets say I have a matrix where there's an `id` column that doesn't go up by 1 with each row.

```
m <- matrix(c(1, "a", "c", 
              5, "g", "c", 
              4, "b", "c", 
              9, "g", "a"),
     ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(m) <- c("id", "class", "type")
```

I've tried renaming the rows with `rownames(m) <- NULL` or `rownames(m) <- c()` but I always end up with an output that has the row numbers on the very left:

```
     id  class type
[1,] "1" "a"   "c" 
[2,] "5" "g"   "c" 
[3,] "4" "b"   "c" 
[4,] "9" "g"   "a"
```

Further more, if I print to PDF in knitr, I get ## running down the side:

```
##      id  class type
## [1,] "1" "a"   "c" 
## [2,] "5" "g"   "c" 
## [3,] "4" "b"   "c" 
## [4,] "9" "g"   "a"
```

I would like to print a pdf that just has the data that I entered into the matrix:

```
id  class type
"1" "a"   "c" 
"5" "g"   "c" 
"4" "b"   "c" 
"9" "g"   "a"
```

Comment: have you considered casting as a data frame instead?

Comment: The "##" is controlled by the `comment` option in `knitr`, which applies to all printed output. See https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#code-decoration . You can get around that by using things like `kable` which transform the output into properly formatted tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `kable` from the `knitr` package.

```
m <- matrix(
  c(1, "a", "c", 5, "g", "c", 4, "b", "c", 9, "g", "a"),
  ncol=3,
  byrow=TRUE
)

colnames(m) <- c("id", "class", "type")

knitr::kable(m)

# |id |class |type |
# |:--|:-----|:----|
# |1  |a     |c    |
# |5  |g     |c    |
# |4  |b     |c    |
# |9  |g     |a    |
```

[image]

You could also read up on the excellent `kableExtra` package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html), which will allow you some great formatting options.

> **N.B.** My initial answer included casting as a data frame, which remains my usual workflow when creating tables. However as was pointed out, `kable` will happily accept a matrix as input.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the best option for me. However I'm using some forloops to output my dataframes, and a lot of objects aren't printed unless explicitly called with print. It appears knitr:kable() is one of them. If I call it with print is loses all its formatting. Do you know a way around this?

Comment: @NicholasHassan, that is really a separate question, however, you can consider using `results='asis'` is your chunk or there is also the `pander` package that is particularly good at this. Otherwise, you are correct to use `print` as noted [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/886)